# Rspec: variables not available in different scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, scope

This is the test that is giving me the error:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Todo, type: :model do    
    it { should have_many(:items).dependent(:destroy) }
end
```

When I run

```
$ rspec
```

I get this error

```
F

Failures:

  1) Todo 
     Failure/Error: example.run
       `name` is not available from within an example (e.g. an `it` block) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc). It is only available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block).
     # ./spec/spec_helper.rb:50:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/spec_helper.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I change the test to in an attempt to fix to the error

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Todo, type: :model do
  describe { should have_many(:items).dependent(:destroy) }
end
```

I run

```
$ rspec
```

and I get

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/models/todo_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: describe { should have_many(:items).dependent(:destroy) }
  `have_many` is not available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block). It is only available from within individual examples (e.g. `it` blocks) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc).
# ./spec/models/todo_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
# ./spec/models/todo_spec.rb:7:in `block in <main>'
# ./spec/models/todo_spec.rb:3:in `<main>'
No examples found.


Finished in 0.00006 seconds (files took 1.45 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples
```

How can I end this never-ending cycle?

[This](https://github.com/IvanDerlich/backup-court-reservation) is the repo.

[This](https://github.com/IvanDerlich/backup-court-reservation/blob/master/spec/models/todo_spec.rb) is the file of the picture I was working on.

Edit:

I solved the problem by initializing the project again. I didn't lose a lot of time because the project was not very advanced. Anyways, I created a repo for the old project so anyone can see the error there.

Comment: I found this [issue](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/2417) on GitHub, which is solved in rspec_rails 4.0.1.

Comment: Can you please code and paste the code and the output into your question instead of linking images. First, that makes the error message searchable and allows other people having the same problem to find this question and the answer in the future. Seconds, it makes it easier for people who want to help you, because they can copy and paste your code to test it and they need to type less when they want to answer.

Comment: Please, post text as text, not as photographs of text. This is a website for programmers, not photographers. We want to copy&paste&run your code, copy&paste your inputs, read your outputs, and copy&paste&google your error messages, not critique your use of color and perspective. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2988 https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Comment: Thanks guys for the feedback. Yes, it makes sense to use text instead of images. I didn't know it.

Comment: I'll be changing the images into text as soon as I get into the office.

Comment: Note that the first error is not in your spec file, it is in spec_helper.rb. What is in spec/spec_helper.rb around line 50?

Comment: @Schwern It's the Database Cleaner gen that cleans the database before every test

Comment: @IvanDerlich It would help to see the actual spec_helper.rb, the problem is there. Your second try is simply incorrect rspec. Also, do other rspec tests work?

Comment: @Schwern Here you have it: https://github.com/IvanDerlich/backup-court-reservation/blob/master/spec/spec_helper.rb
I solved this by initializing the project again

Comment: @IvanDerlich Thanks. I ran `bundle` and `rails db:setup` and `it { should have_many(:items).dependent(:destroy) }` Works For Me™

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is arising due to the compatibility of previous `rspec-rails` versions with the latest versions of `rails`. I can see that you are using 3.x version. So, the solution is to use the latest version of `rspec-rails`.

> As per rspec-rails documentation, Use `rspec-rails 4.x` for Rails from 5.0 to 6.0. Use rspec-rails 3.x for Rails earlier than 5.0. Use rspec-rails 1.x for Rails 2.x.

Comment: I run: 'bunlder update rspec-core rspec-expectations rspec-mocks rspec-rails rspec-support' and the error persists

Comment: It was a failure. I updated rails to 5.0.1 and the error persists.

Comment: I deleted all the gems related to rspec, installed everything again and the problem persists.

Comment: I tried rspec-rails versions 4.0.1 and 4.0.2 with the same result.

Comment: @IvanDerlich This works, but you broke your test. Change one thing at a time. Revert your test back to `it { should have_many(:items).dependent(:destroy) }`